# How to Create a CSS3 Animated Circle that chages colors when clicked?

Tags: html, css, css-animations, mouseclick-event, dom-events

How would you code in HTML5 and CSS3 a page that contains a couple of circles that move around (aimlessly) and change colors when clicked.  The colors could be any or just a back and forth between two.  I am try to do this purely as a learning example and in CSS - no JS.

Comment: That's typically something you'd need to write code for I'm afraid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the circle create a square and set its border radius to `50%`.

```
.circle{
   width:50px;
   height:50px;
   display:block;
   border-radius:50%;
}
```

to move it around set it position to `absolute` or `fixed` (*depends where you want it constrained*) and then animate it using keyframes.

You cannot make it move randomly without CSS, but you can define a complex path.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_animations

---

**Update**

A small demo (*without vendor prefixes*)

```css
.circle{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius:50%;
  position:fixed;
  background-color:red;
  
  /*center it*/
  margin-left: -25px;
  margin-top: -25px;
}

.move-1{
   animation: rombus 10s linear 0s infinite;
}

@keyframes rombus{
   0%{left:50%;top:0}
   25%{left:100%;top:50%}
   50%{left:50%;top:100%}
   75%{left:0;top:50%}
   100%{left:50%;top:0}
}
```

```html
<div class="circle move-1"></div>
```

---

To add click handling it gets a bit more complicated as to handle state in html you only have checkboxes..

So changes are needed in both html and css. It might not be really applicable for real use.

```css
.circle{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius:50%;
  display:block;
  background-color:red;
}
:checked + .circle{background-color:green;}


.animated-circle{
  position:fixed;
  display:block;
  border-radius:50%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;  
  
  /*center it*/
  margin-left: -25px;
  margin-top: -25px;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.animated-circle input{display:none;}

.move-1{
   animation: rombus 20s linear 0s infinite;
}

@keyframes rombus{
   0%{left:50%;top:0}
   25%{left:100%;top:50%}
   50%{left:50%;top:100%}
   75%{left:0;top:50%}
   100%{left:50%;top:0}
}
```

```html
<label class="animated-circle move-1"><input type="checkbox" /><div class="circle"></div></label>
```

Comment: Perfect - can you add a click change color without JS?  I know how I would do it with JS as when clicked change css color, but is there a css/html answer?

Comment: @RooksStrife added an update which allows to toggle the color with clicking. It is a bit more involved though..

Answer (score 2):

You can use additional css selector as `+`.
Here example, no js: http://jsfiddle.net/j3o7y237/
Work at ie8 and gte.
Plus animation from answer above this: http://jsfiddle.net/j3o7y237/1/